# Search Filter by mime type not working in pre_get_posts

Tags: search, pre-get-posts, mime-types

I'm trying to create a search option for users to display only PDF attachment posts. The following works to display all attachments:

```
function CustomSearchFilter($query) {
  if( (! is_admin() ) && ($query->is_search)) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'attachment' );    
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts','CustomSearchFilter');
```

But when I try to filter it to a single mime type it still displays all attachments:

```
function CustomSearchFilter($query) {
  if( (! is_admin() ) && ($query->is_search)) {
    $query->set('post_mime_type', 'application/pdf');
    $query->set('post_type', 'attachment' );    
  }
}  
add_filter('pre_get_posts','CustomSearchFilter');
```

What am I doing wrong?